# PHP - After Decrypting, How can I offer the user a OPEN / SAVE file option from the browser without having to save the file first?

Tags: php, html, forms, file, encryption

So I have a little test app where the user can upload a file (docx,png,jpg and a few others). The file is encrypted and saved to a folder. A DB Table entry is created with the UID of the user and the filename eg

```
AA1234   Image100.jpg
BB2345   WorkDoc.Doc
```

This works just fine, the file is encrypted and saved and the table contains the info.

To download a saved, encrypted file, the user is given a select/option from a list of the files applicable to them (eg Image100.jpg by me, AA1234). On submit, the tool should then load the file, decrypt it and open the window to allow the user to OPEN/SAVE the file

My issue is that although this works, its not as tidy as I'd like. The code loads the file, decrypts it, **saves it as a decrypted temporary file** and then offers the user the OPEN/SAVE window based on this temporary saved file as per below. (it then deletes this temp, decrypted file after).

```
include('./lib/key.php');

//Get the filename and prepend the folder where the encrypted files are saved
$file = ('encuploads/'.$_POST["fileToDownload"]);

//Read the file and convert it to a string variable
$DocumentString = file_get_contents($file);

//Decrypt the file
$decryption=openssl_decrypt ($DocumentString, $ciphering, $key, $options, $iv); 

//Create a new temporary file containing the decrypted info
$decrypt = 'decrypted'.basename($_POST["fileToDownload"]);
$downloadfile = 'encuploads/'.$decrypt;
file_put_contents($downloadfile, $decryption);

//change the headers to output to a "download/save" window for the user
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . ($_POST["fileToDownload"]) . "\";");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($downloadfile));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($downloadfile); //showing the path to the server where the file is to be download

//delete the temporary file.
unlink(realpath($downloadfile))
```

So instead of saving the temp decrypted file - `"file_put_contents($downloadfile, $decryption);"` and then reading it with the headers set `"readfile($downloadfile);"` I would like to have the option to straight use the $decryption variable after the header statements

such as `echo $decryption` with headers set so that it give the user the same OPEN/SAVE options (for the type of file chosen)

Any idea if this is a valid option or any other tidy way of giving the user a download option after decryption (I dont want a `<a href="decryptedfilehere">DOWNLOAD</a>` option ... I would like the popup window)

Thanks

Comment: I assume this is just an exercise, but it is not really safe if I give you my file, you encrypt it and you keep the keys so you can decrypt it. You could do that anytime. Or anyone at your end could do it. A bit like saying _"Here are the Crown Jewels, you **will** be careful with them **wont you**"_ ?

Comment: But in answer to your question, why cannot you just `echo $decryption;` instead of `readfile($downloadfile);`

Comment: Its being encrypted so that other users trying to get into that folder - cant open other users files. they have no idea of the encryption parameters....

Comment: Yes, but you do. Your admin does, and probably your coder(s) do. Know the keys I mean, so this is as secure as a Cullender

Comment: Never give your data to someone else to encrypt, do it yourself, then just give the encrypted file to someone to look after is you want